# Continuously differentiable function so that $u(0,0) =0$ and can be written as sum of two continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Question: Prove or provide a counterexample to the following statement. If $u \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable so that $u(0,0) =0$. Then, there exists continuous function $g, h\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ so that
> $$u(x,y) = x g(x,y) + y h(x,y)\ \text{for all}\ x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My attempt: I believe this statement is true where $g(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y), h(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)$. However, I am aware that the taylor's formula involves remainder terms, then tends to $0$ near $(0,0)$. However, I am not sure how to ensure these remainder terms are identically zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Edit: The above approach is false, as attributed by the following example $u(x,y) = \sin(x)$ suggested in the comments.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Suppose, say, that $u(x,y)=\sin(x)$. You have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\cos(x)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. Are you claiming then that$$\left(\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\right):u(x,y)=\sin(x)=x\cos(x)?$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you are right, I have made some edits.

Comment: Have a look at the first formula in  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3805831/42969, it should answer your question.

Comment: @MartinR thank you again